# Heroku Failed Push

Tags: python, heroku, error-handling, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to push something towards heroku with the command: "git push heroku HEAD:main"

The error i get inside of the CMD is:

```
    "! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
      error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/discordbotonline247.git'"
    
     And if i check Heroku logs i find this:
    -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
    
    -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
    
    -----> Python app detected
    
    -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.9
    
           To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
    
    -----> Installing python-3.9.9
    
    -----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
    
    -----> Installing SQLite3
    
    -----> Installing requirements with pip
    
           Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite (from -r /tmp/build_3181f09c/requirements.txt (line 1))
    
             Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to revision rewrite) to /tmp/pip-req-build-wpl2aq36
    
             Running command git clone --filter=blob:none -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py /tmp/pip-req-build-wpl2aq36
    
             WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'rewrite', assuming revision or ref.
    
             Running command git checkout -q rewrite
    
             error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git
    
           WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite. Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs for full command output.
    
           ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs for full command output.
    
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
    
     !     Push failed
```

in my Procfile i have:

```
"worker: python Discord_Bot.py
```

In my requirements.txt i have:

```
"git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite
 PyNaCl==1.3.0
 pandas
 dnspython==1.16.0
 async-timeout==3.0.1"
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the quotation marks in your requirement.txt file along with the @rewrite in the Github link. However, instead of removing the @rewrite, just specify the discord version. Replace your requirements.txt file with the following:

```
discord.py==1.6.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pandas
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

Comment: Tysm maybe you can help aswel with the comment i posted, it was to large to comment it under here

Comment: @SdejSdeyt First, please mark my answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark below the downvote button so that others viewing this question know that this answer works. Second, please post your new question as a separate one instead of in this thread.

Comment: Okay i will do that

Comment: Ty for the fast commenting!